# How to prove the Apache web server is not accepting connections anymore because of an denial of service attack (Slowloris)?

Tags: apache, denial-of-service

I have a network dump (PCAP file) from a "conversation" between a web server apache (192.168.1.2) and some clients:

[image: PCAP File]

What a should look for to prove that the server buffer (or TCP WINDOW) is full? I received 403 error (error.log). I know it was a denial of service attack (slowloris).

Comment: Please explain more about your config: 1. Are you located on the apache server, on any in-the-middle router or elsewhere? 2. What kind of os are you using a) on server, b) where you're located.

Comment: ... and what's your goal: learning something, prevent attacks or to build some *honeypot*?

Comment: @F. Hauri: Thanks. This simulation is part of a reserch project about denial of service.My goal is understand the attack!

Comment: ... And what about your environment? ... and please instead of answering to comments, edit your request!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### With `.pcap` file

Unfortunely, you can't ask for server status, while just looking for communication line.

But, you could count how many different connection are opened by one ip:

```
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -anr myfile.pcap |
    sed 's/^.*IP \([^:]*\)192.168.1.2.80:.*/\1/p;d' |
    sort |
    uniq -c
```

This will show a lot of

```
          10 192.168.1.8.36684 >
           4 192.168.1.8.39619 >
           9 192.168.1.8.39856 >
           4 192.168.1.8.39896 >
           5 192.168.1.8.40195 >
          12 192.168.1.8.40196 >
           9 192.168.1.8.52288 >
           7 192.168.1.8.58529 >
           9 192.168.1.8.58639 >
           9 192.168.1.8.58730 >
           6 192.168.1.8.58835 >
          13 192.168.1.8.58851 >
          12 192.168.1.8.58852 >
          10 192.168.1.8.58882 >
```

You could try to count how many connection per seconds, but how many maintened open connection is stronger.

#### *Near* real time

If  located on a proxy, a router or the server himself, you could trace real time connections with

```
tcpdump -ani eth0 host 192.168.1.2 and port 80 |
    sed -une '
      s/^\(.\{8\}\).* IP \(.*\)\.[0-9]\+ > 192.168.1.2.80: Flags \[S\],.*/\1 \2/p
    '
```

If too much output, you could count connection by sec, with a little delay due to `uniq` bufferisation and count

```
tcpdump -ani eth0 host 192.168.1.2 and port 80 |
    sed -une '
      s/^\(.\{8\}\).* IP \(.*\)\.[0-9]\+ > 192.168.1.2.80: Flags \[S\],.*/\1 \2/p
    ' |
    uniq -c
```

#### Next step

If based on Linux, you may start to play with `iptables` to build triggers for this kind of attacks, have a look there:

[How to best defend against a “slowloris” DOS attack against an Apache web server?  @ serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/32361/how-to-best-defend-against-a-slowloris-dos-attack-against-an-apache-web-server)

Comment: :"You could try to count how many connection per seconds, but how many maintened open connection is stronger". How can I do it using Python. for example? Thanks!

Comment: If on server, you could use `netstat` but on intermediate router, there is no way.

Comment: ( I'm not 100% sure about previous comment. I have to confirm them... )

Comment: "You could try to count how many connection per seconds, but how many maintened open connection is stronger" But, is it possible after the attack? or can I look into the PCAP file?

Comment: :How can I sum the number of connections? For example: 10 +4+9+... +10? Using a script?

Comment: You could simply use `wc -l`, for sample.

Comment: Question about programming (in python or else) could be asked on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: :How to count how many opened connection per seconds (in PCAP file)?

Comment: U could use the command under ***Near real time*** and replace `-i eth0` by `-r .pcapfile`. The second one, with `uniq -c`, will do the job.

Comment: ... You may replace `uniq -c` by `sort | uniq -c`.

Comment: :Is it regex? Where Can I learn about?

Comment: Is it correct?


http://imgur.com/a/Aok4g

Comment: Yes, it's [*regex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `man sed`, `info sed`. And yes, this seem correct!